# How do i solve compound interest questions like this?

Tags: finance

How do i solve compound interest questions like this? Do I just use the compound interest formula directly?

If I have lets say $500 in a savings account for 5 years and it earns 2.5% Annual equivalent rate compounded monthly. How much will I have now?

Or should I use the Annual equivalent rate formula for compounding monthly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you gain $2.5\%$ in one year, you gain $0.21\%$ per month.

You can calculate the amount of money you have $x$ with:

$x=x_0g^{t/\tau}$, with $x_0$ your starting amount, $g$ the growth factor, and $\tau$ is the timescale.

If you calculate in years, $\tau = 1$ year, $g=1.025$, 
for months: $\tau = 1$ month, $g=(1.025)^\frac{1}{12}$

Comment: But I don't know what to do next. How should I calculate in 5years time

Comment: for that, t=5 years, then fill in the formula. I can't tell you anymore without spoiling the answer, but if that is what you want, tell me so.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got 565.70. Is that correct?

Comment: That is the same as I got, nice.

Comment: Appreciate the help